# I don't understand C++11 conditional_variable specifics on detached threads

Tags: multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I have got two pieces of code running in detached threads appropriately:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck( interThreadLockMtx );

    //std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lckGiveCond( mtxCondVar );

    condVarGivePasswd.notify_one();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lckCond( condVarTakePasswdMtx );
    condVarTakePasswd.wait( lckCond );

    passwd = newPasswd;
}
```

and

```
    for (;;)
    {
        std::unique_lock<decltype(mtxCondVar)> mtxCondVarLock( mtxCondVar );
        condVarGivePasswd.wait( mtxCondVarLock );
        newPasswd = genNewPasswd();
        //std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lckCond( condVarTakePasswdMtx );
        condVarTakePasswd.notify_one();
    }
```

I run this code compiled with clang++ on Mac OS X Mavericks and it appears to me that notify_one calls have no effect since both threads remain blocked on wait condition_variable::wait calls. Does anybody have any idea on what is going wrong here?

Here is a bit of debugging that reveals that cv's are getting blocked upon wait calls:

```
Process 63102 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x142f17, 0x00007fff86fba716 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10,     queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
thread #2: tid = 0x142f31, 0x00007fff86fba716 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
thread #3: tid = 0x142f32, 0x00007fff86fba746 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
thread #4: tid = 0x142f33, 0x00007fff86fba746 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
thread #5: tid = 0x142f34, 0x00007fff86fba746 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
```

It seems that I'm having race conditions here with `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` that is mandatory for wait call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I'm having race conditions here with std::unique_lock that is mandatory for wait call. I just removed all condition_variables and left controlling thread do nothing. Instead working threads do their work themselves w/o requesting info from controlling thread.